# Pandas joining on index is producing all NaN for right-side DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter, data-science, jupyter-lab

I am trying to join two pandas DataFrames on index.  The both have the same number of rows and everything about the index appears to be correct.  However, when I run the code,

```
df1=df2.join(df3)
```

iIt produces all NaN for df3's values.  I have been searching google for a while now and have no idea why.

I have tried casting into pandas data frames and also reset_index.  Neither did the trick.

```
df1=df2.join(df3)
```

producing all `NaN` for df3's columns

In the expected results the NaN's would all have the values of df3.  The actual results are producing all NaN.

Comment: Without taking a look at the dataframes, df1,df2, df3, your code and then the output that you get, there is not much anyone can do to help.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will upload now.  How do you recommend I display my data frames, there are 1460 rows.  thanks!!

Comment: Display just a sample with few rows. Try to reproduce the problem with say 5-10 rows.

Comment: You can just display the first few. Thanks!

Comment: Use `df.head()` to output the first few rows of each dataframe then add to your question. Use `df.dtypes` to show the data type of each column in your dataframe and add as well.

Comment: what about just concating `pd.concat([df1,df2]axis=1)` ?

Comment: I am working on uploading the heads of my dataframes, but am having some trouble.  When I use concat, it says "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/api.py:87: RuntimeWarning: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int', sort order is undefined for incomparable objects
  result = result.union(other)

Comment: Hi guys.  I am having trouble uploading the head of my DataFrames.  Here is what is happening when I copy/paste: 
LCBnk2 LCHLS2 LCLow2 LCLvl2
0 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 1
2 0 0 0 1
3 0 0 0 1
4 0 0 0 1

Comment: @MattGoralka: Paste your code inside backticks (``) or indent to auto-format. See [SO's syntax guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Hi guys.  Thanks for all your help!  I figured it out I needed to change the index types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer to this was to change the index types on both my dataframes.  In my particular instance I converted to string.  Thanks!